# Trying to set input to variable using $_POST["name of input"], but the variable comes out blank

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, .htaccess

I currently have a script in HTML that does the following:

There is a dropdown menu with the choices being a number between 1 - 4.

When a value is selected, the corresponding number of textboxes "appear" beneath the dropdown menu. The user can then input values into the textboxes.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#elementreg").on("change", function() {
      var val = $(this).val();

      $('.types').hide(); //hide all
      $(`#${val}`).show(); //show by matching the selected value
    });
  });
</script>

<label for="How Many Chips">How Many Chips?:</label>

<select class="medium" id="elementreg" name="amount">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<div class="types" id="1">
  <input name="First Chip ID">
</div>

<div class="types" id="2">
  <input name="First Chip ID">
  <input name="Second Chip ID">
</div>

<div class="types" id="3">
  <input name="First Chip ID">
  <input name="Second Chip ID">
  <input name="Third Chip ID">
</div>

<div class="types" id="4">
  <input name="First Chip ID">
  <input name="Second Chip ID">
  <input name="Third Chip ID">
  <input name="Fourth Chip ID">
</div>
```

This portion of the code works as intended, at least visually.

Using php, I would like to grab each non-empty input, set it to a variable, and write a string containing the non-empty chip ID's to a text file. To accomplish this, I wrote the following:

```html
<?php>
    //Get the value of the First Chip ID, Second Chip ID, Third Chip ID, 
    //and Fourth Chip ID inputs
    $FirstChipID = "";
    $SecondChipID = "";
    $ThirdChipID = "";
    $FourthChipID = "";

    if (!empty($_POST["First Chip ID"])) {
        $FirstChipID = $_POST["First Chip ID"] . ", ";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST["Second Chip ID"])) {
        $SecondChipID = $_POST["Second Chip ID"] . ", ";;
    }

    if (!empty($_POST["Third Chip ID"])) {
        $ThirdChipID = $_POST["Third Chip ID"] . ", ";;
    }

    if (!empty($_POST["Fourth Chip ID"])) {
        $FourthChipID = $_POST["Fourth Chip ID"] . ", ";; 
    }

    $file = fopen("chipID.txt", "a");
    fwrite($file, $FirstChipID . $SecondChipID . $ThirdChipID .
    $FourthChipID . $Comments . $photo . "\n");
    fclose($file);
?>
```

However, when running the code, the file comes out empty. Am I overwriting the value of the chip id's to be blank each time? Or is there something wrong with my logic? Is it within the php portion or the html portion?

Any and all guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is the `form`(?) being submitted? Why is the question tagged `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how (or even "if") your `form`(?) or series of form elements are being submitted to your PHP script. However, there are a couple of flaws with the code you have posted:

1. Your `name` attributes contain *spaces*. Whilst this is "permitted" in HTML, when PHP receives the request the *spaces* are converted to underscores in the `$_POST` superglobal. So you would need to read `$_POST["First_Chip_ID"]` instead. It is recommended to avoid the use of spaces in the `name` attribute.
2. You have multiple instances of `input` elements with the same `name` in the HTML. For instance, you have four `<input name="First Chip ID">` elements. Unless you have some ("hacky") JavaScript that extracts only the values you are interested in (in order to construct a POST request), an ordinary `form` submission will only POST the last instance of each form element - which may not be the one with the (current) value you are interested in.

   You should ensure you only have 1 instance of each named `input` element. You then need to change your script so that only the same `input` elements are hidden/shown. And perhaps toggle the `readonly` attribute (and/or clear the value) on "hidden" elements at the same time, although you should be checking the `$_POST['amount']` value to determine which fields to check in your PHP script.